# Ajax Load more CPT via shortcode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with ajax load more for my CustomPostType. I think i have mistake but don't know where. If it possible to edit my code, i will happy.

**UPDATE**

I have create div `cool` to paste in it loaded more post. After clicking load more i have 0 in div cool. What does it mean?

**In functions.php**

```
    add_shortcode( 'list-posts-basic', 'rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1' );

function rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'imggal',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    ) );


    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <ul id="ajaxx" class="clothes-listing">
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <div id="cool"></div>
            <a id="more_posts" href="#">Load More</a>
        </ul>
    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1', 'rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1', 'rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1');
```

**AJAX**

```
   (function($) {  
$(document).ready(function($) {   
    $("#more_posts").on("click",function(e){ // When btn is pressed.
    e.preventDefault();


        $.ajax({  
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,  
        data: {  
              'action' : 'rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1'  
          },   
        success: function (data) {  
              if (data.length > 0) {  
                $('#cool').html(data);  
              }
          },
      });

   });

   });    
})(jQuery);
```

Please help me!

Comment: "I think I have problem". Can you at least try and explain _what_ the problem is - is [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? Do you get any server-side errors? Do you get any client-side errors (in your browser console)? No-one is going to make the effort of setting up a local install & running & testing your code if you're not going to make any effort when asking your question.

Comment: The problem is one - posts not loaded. no errors. nothing. Can you help me to write ajax function? look edit

Comment: Multiple notes: You only return the `if` case from `rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1()`, while you might want to return a fail state as well. The same goes for your JS AJAX request. You only have a `success` function and even in there you only return anything in case you have something inside `data`. You might want to extend your whole return policy.

Answer (score 1):

This will (*should) fix your first problem:

```
function rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1( $atts ) {
    // No need for output buffering - AJAX handlers should ECHO their response
    // ob_start();

    // ..

    // So long, farewell
    // $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    // return $myvariable;

    // Now terminate
    exit;
}
```

Your second problem is that you are not implementing any kind of pagination/increment in your AJAX handler - "load more" will always load the same post.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that your AJAX function in `functions.php` should `echo` its results, not `return`. You also need a call to `wp_die()` at the end.

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do but it looks like half of your loop probably shouldn't be there. Currently you are outputing the whole `#ajaxx` list inside itself every time you click `#load-more`. Which at the *very least* will give you problems with duplicate IDs.

I suspect what you want is:

**whatever-page-template.php**

```
// Rest of page template and beginning of loop

<ul id="ajaxx" class="clothes-listing">

    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <div id="cool"></div>
    <a id="more_posts" href="#">Load More</a>
</ul>

// etc...
```

**functions.php**

```
function rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1( $atts )
{
    ob_start();

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'imggal',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    ));

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    echo $myvariable;

    wp_die();
}
```

You are also always loading the same post so you need to implement some kind of pagination, but I would get the basic AJAX call fixed first!

You can read more about AJAX in Wordpress (including debugging!) here:

- [WordPress - AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Answer (score -1):

You should consider giving the Ajax Load More WordPress plugin a try.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/